# How to fix this date regular expression that is matching things it should not

Tags: python, regex, date

I am trying to scan some documents to find dates for a classification problem.  After reading around here and some other places I have constructed the following regular expression

```
months='['+'|'.join(calendar.month_abbr[1:])+'|'+'|'.join(calendar.month_name[1:])+']'
techPart='+\\.*\\s*\\d{1,2}[,]?[\\s*][1|2]\\d{3}'
dateExpr=months+techPart
```

I am testing it on this string

```
newString='Mar. 31, 2011 Dec. 31, 2010 bananas Mar. 31, 2011 too much malarky September 1, 1992 redundant Dec. 31, 2010  September 29, 1999  March 12 2004 ddfd  March.    13 2019 ddfd  Mac.    13 2019 ddfd'
```

and when I run it like this

```
for date in re.findall(dateExpr,newString):
print date
```

I get this

```
Mar. 31, 2011
Dec. 31, 2010
Mar. 31, 2011
September 1, 1992
Dec. 31, 2010
September 29, 1999
March 12 2004
March.    13 2019
Mac.    13 2019    #here is my problem
```

Comment: Use `r''` raw strings instead of double-escaping everything; e.g. `r'+\.*\s*\d{1,2}[,]?[\s*][1|2]\d{3}'`.

Comment: Actually I am sorry I did but to get the value from my code to here I typed techPart and then copied the value into my question as I wanted to make sure I did not screw things up when asking the question so it shows up as double slashes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `months` regex, you are using square brackets, giving something like `[Jan|Feb|Mar|...]`.  That is wrong. Square brackets are for character classes and match *one* of any character in the brackets, so this will match `J` or `a` or `n` or `|` or `F`, etc.  Instead you want to use parentheses:

```
months='(?:'+'|'.join(calendar.month_abbr[1:])+'|'+'|'.join(calendar.month_name[1:])+')'
```

You need the `?:` because `findall` returns only captured groups, so we need to mark this group as noncapturing.

You have the same problem later in your regex where you do `[1|2]`.  You want `(?:1|2)`, or just `[12]`.

Comment: Can't you simplify this to `months='(' + '|'.join(calendar.month_abbr[1:] + calendar.month_name[1:]) + ')'`?

Comment: Well thanks but that throws up something else.  It passed over the rest of the date.  So I then tried to make the months a nested group by putting parenthesis around the whole expression after first following your suggestion and it picks up a following month so it does not completely fix the problem

Comment: @PyNEwbie: I can't follow what you're saying there.  If it's not working, please edit your question to give an example of what is going wrong.

Comment: @BrenBarn Your suggestion doesn't work as you expected because of the `findall`. For instance `print ''.join(re.findall('[Jan|Feb]', "Jan|Feb"))` will output `Jan|Feb`

Comment: My test shows it outputting Feb but only if the rest of the date is present 'Jan|Feb xyz' will not output anything but 'Jan|Feb 12, 2004' will output Feb

Comment: @PyNewbie: Again, please edit your question to provide actual examples of what you want and are not getting.  Your initial code is only set up to match an entire date, so I don't get what you mean about matching "Jan" or "Feb" by itself.

Comment: @BrenBarn Your solution only matches the month it does not give me the full date but it correctly pulls the month if it is valid it only reports the month if the rest of the date is present put it does not give the full date in the output

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Ah, I see the problem.  The expression matches everything, but findall only returns captured groups, so it's only returning the month.  See my edited answer.  If you use `(?:` instead (marking the group as noncapturing) then it works.

Comment: Thanks so much I was working there as I checked for your reply